# Vagrant machine unreachable from the outside

Tags: networking, vagrant

When I mean "from the outside", I mean from the internet.

My machine is behind a router. And I'm running vagrant to bring up 3 machines. Here's the vagrant file (I removed the fluff):

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-20.04"
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox

  mount_new_disk = <<-SCRIPT
  sudo mkdir /mnt/da
  sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb
  sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt/da
  SCRIPT

  config.vm.define "da1" do |da1|
    da1.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
      da1.vm.hostname = "da1"
      da1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.118.8.10"
      config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  end

  config.vm.define "da2" do |da2|
    da2.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
    da2.vm.disk :disk, name: "backup", size: "10GB"
      da2.vm.hostname = "da2"
      da2.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.118.8.11"
      config.ssh.forward_agent = true
    config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => mount_new_disk
  end

  config.vm.define "da3" do |da3|
    da3.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
    da3.vm.disk :disk, name: "backup", size: "10GB"
    da3.vm.hostname = "da3"
    da3.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.118.8.12"
      da3.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.1.155", netmask: "255.255.255.0", bridge: "Intel(R) I211 Gigabit Network Connection"
    da3.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 5555
      config.ssh.forward_agent = true
    config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => mount_new_disk
  end
end
```

Sshd config on the vm:

```
testuser1@da3:~$ head -20 /etc/ssh/sshd_config|grep -v '#'
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

Port 22
AddressFamily any
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
ListenAddress ::
```

And it is possible to connect to it from any terminal on my computer using it's bridged ip (`192.168.1.155`):

```
D:\vag_rant>ssh testuser1@192.168.1.155
testuser1@192.168.1.155's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-58-generic x86_64)
```

Firewall is down on it:

```
testuser1@da3:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

This is the output of `ip addr` on the vm:

```
testuser1@da3:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:14:86:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 86205sec preferred_lft 86205sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe14:86db/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:86:38:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.118.8.12/24 brd 10.118.8.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe86:38bf/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:5a:fa:4c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.155/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe5a:fa4c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I opened `port 22` on the router to ip `192.168.1.155`.

Everything so far looks good. I did this before with just a VM that ONLY has a bridged network adapter, and it worked. It was accessible from the outside.

But this doesn't work, for some reason. Nobody can access my machine from the outside using my public IP...

After a bit of work, I made progress, now it just says `no route to host`.

Comment: It would be great if you could ask a question. What exactly do you expect from Stackexchange? In any case, had I this problem, I would double-check the router configuration, then check if the router knows where to send traffic destined to 192.168.1.155. If those tests are positive, I would trace traffic between router, VM host and VM guest. Most likely, your problem is not on the VM's side, but somewhere on the router, the Windows PC that hosts the VM, or the network between them, so that it is not really on-topic for Unix.Stackexchange.com.

Comment: My question is: why isn't it working? Also how would I check if the router knows where to send the traffic meant for `155`?

Comment: Nobody can answer this question without knowing your configuration. And I can't tell you how to check your router - this varies from model to model. Some routers allow you to access their command line, others have test pages, others might not have any troubleshooting features at all.

Comment: @berndbausch I'm pretty sure it doesn't offer such features, but it does have a client list, and my machine, that's using a bridged connection, isn't on the client list on the router, and when I had VMs with bridged conenctions in the past, they appeared there. It also doesn't have an available shell. I did set up a static IP for the VM on the router though, but still doesn't work.

Comment: To understand why traffic doesn't arrive at the VM, you need to check the points between the internet and the VM where traffic forwarding decisions are made. And if I understand you correctly, they are the router and the VM host. If you can't check the router directly, trace traffic (wireshark, tcpdump, other tools) to see what happens.

Comment: I've never done that before, I don't know how to use said tools, or what to do with them lol

Comment: Well I resolved a part of the mystery. Long story short, I was an idiot and had port 22 open on another machine... (one that doesn't exist anymore). To make things worse, I tried an apache server and still didn't work, turns out I also had port 80 open on another machine xD, now it works but only if the bridged adapter is the only one, but I still don't know how to get it to work with more adapters, one of which is the bridged. EDIT: apache server works, but ssh (and weirdly enough curl) don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Found the problem. The same port 22 was forwarded to a different machine on the router. When I resolved that problem, there was one more problem. The default gateway on the vagrant machine was that of the virtualbox adapter. I had to modify it to be the default gateway of the router, then it worked.

```
root@da3:/home/testuser1# ip route show
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.0.2.15 metric 100
default via 192.168.1.254 dev eth2 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.104 metric 100
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15
10.0.2.2 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 100
10.118.8.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.118.8.12
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.104
192.168.1.254 dev eth2 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.104 metric 100
root@da3:/home/testuser1# ip route del default via 10.0.2.2
root@da3:/home/testuser1# ip route show
default via 192.168.1.254 dev eth2 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.104 metric 100
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15
10.0.2.2 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 100
10.118.8.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.118.8.12
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.104
192.168.1.254 dev eth2 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.104 metric 100
```

Comment: check this command: vagrant ssh-config